# Bootsrap "zebra-striped" table class doesn't work

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Just downloaded Bootstrap from getboostrap.com ([direct link](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.0.3/bootstrap-3.0.3-dist.zip)), then correctly included 
bootstrap.min.css, bootstrap-theme.min.css and bootstrap.min.js into my document.

I styled my forms successfully, now I want to add the "zebra-striped" class to my tables. But nothing happens, the TR and TD elements in the table don't get the class applied to them. I searched "zebra-striped" in the 3 files (2 CSS and 1 JS), it's not there.

Version problem? Or should I install some Bootstrap add-on?

Comment: please inspect your table DOM with firebug and include the applied CSS   in your question, that will explain your problem better

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hello this is the right class for table stripped

```
<table class="table table-striped">
  ...
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">   
<head>   
<meta charset="utf-8">   
<title>Example of Zebra Table with twitter bootstrap</title>   
<meta name="description" content="Creating a Zebra table with Twitter           Bootstrap. Learn with example of a Zebra Table with Twitter Bootstrap.">  
<link href="/twitter-bootstrap/twitter-bootstrap-  v2/docs/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">   
</head>  
<body>  
<table class="table table-striped">  
    <thead>  
      <tr>  
        <th>Student-ID</th>  
        <th>First Name</th>  
        <th>Last Name</th>  
        <th>Grade</th>  
      </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
      <tr>  
        <td>001</td>  
        <td>Rammohan </td>  
        <td>Reddy</td>  
        <td>A+</td>  
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>002</td>  
        <td>Smita</td>  
        <td>Pallod</td>  
        <td>A</td>  
      </tr>  
      <tr>  
        <td>003</td>  
        <td>Rabindranath</td>  
        <td>Sen</td>  
        <td>A+</td>  
      </tr>  
    </tbody>  
  </table>
```

- See more at: http://www.w3resource.com/twitter-bootstrap/tables-tutorial.php#sthash.NQn0cWnr.dpuf

Answer (score 0):

In case it's helpful for somebody, the stripes were not showing for me because of conflict between styles of bootstrap and angular material design. So if you're doing everything right, look for a possible style conflict.